# Importing Alembic from Mocha to Blender problem

Tags: import

Soo I am trying to bring a mesh from Mocha but when I bring the Alembic file to Blender the thing is not a mesh but separate vertices. After looking in the Blender manual it seems that Alembic files have to come with 'Transform Cache' constrain and a 'Mesh sequence Cache' modifier for each vertex so it can transform it to mesh I guess, but in my case the vertices come only with a 'Transform Cache' constrain.

Any suggestion what maybe I am doing wrong or how can I fix it. Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since you had this question. Anyway, I wanted to jump in as I was having the same problem and wanted to share the solution : ).
When exporting tracking data make sure to export in Alembic Mesh data, Alembic Vertex Transform Data creates the result you were experiencing.

[image]